# Initial value of function in useRef throws an error cause "Argument of type '() => never' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'."

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I try to use the generic parameter type `T` for `useRef`. The default value of `useRef` is a function that throws an error.

```
import { useRef, useEffect, useCallback, DependencyList } from 'react';

export function useEventCallback<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(fn: T, dependencies: DependencyList) {
  const ref = useRef<T>(() => {
    // doesn't work either.
    // return false;
    throw new Error('Cannot call an event handler while rendering.');
    
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = fn;
  }, [fn, ...dependencies]);

  return useCallback(() => {
    const fn = ref.current;
    return fn();
  }, [ref]);
}
```

TSC throws error:

```sh
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(initialValue: T): MutableRefObject<T>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '() => never' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
      '() => never' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '(...args: any[]) => any'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(initialValue: T | null): RefObject<T>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '() => never' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
      '() => never' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '(...args: any[]) => any'.ts(2769)
```

I try to return a value for the function but still got a similar error:

```sh
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(initialValue: T): MutableRefObject<T>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '() => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
      '() => boolean' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '(...args: any[]) => any'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(initialValue: T | null): RefObject<T>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '() => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
      '() => boolean' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '(...args: any[]) => any'.ts(2769)
```

I think the return value of the function is of type `any`, which should be compatible with `never` and `boolean`

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgEQKZlQOwCZYMYCeAMsAM4wA0cArqagMICGANswEaN4DWVtqAogDNBqPJRp0ASqkFwAvnEFQIIOAHIoqTjDUBuALAAoI6gAekWIuqYxwCJgkCAblhhNWHbgB4AKnDMwWNikcAAUAHSRjFAA5qQAXHCMmAQA2gC6AJRwALwAfEkpeaGCmIk+VLgYOPjAqAko6EH4xGQw2QhGcHB49uRwmrI5jtKCvsWh2fmIXd1wMAAWygDucJioq-xQylChakyYmBDweCzMhf4umPALydjMqFBwywvADwPNUMCYMeFqmQZDN05ACjLM+EIRGJQpNcgVOkC5oNwnhqNtXLlFJhAcCqKlSlRIuEqs0bHVSFlAbNNDA0Q4+O52JwuDCpvDZt1eph+qVMcjUejrjikahaVAHKVJsK5HjBpSjHIgA)

Comment: Are you sure it is a good idea to throw an Error inside `userRef`?

Comment: @captain-yossarian It's not "inside useRef" – useRef is just a box for any object.

Comment: @captain-yossarian The initial value of `useRef` is a function that will NOT execute immediately during component render, so yes. I think it's ok. I try to improve the title to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring `useRef` as follows solved this issue:

```
export function useEventCallback<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(fn: T, dependencies: DependencyList) {
  const ref = useRef<T | (() => never)>(() => {
    // works now.
    throw new Error('Cannot call an event handler while rendering.')
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = fn
  }, [fn, ...dependencies])

  return useCallback(() => {
    return ref.current()
  }, [ref])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to make TS happy, you should explicitly provide `never` type (because of the Error) as a return type of `T`

```js
import { DependencyList, useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export function useEventCallback<T extends (...args: any[]) => never>(fn: T, dependencies: DependencyList) {
  const ref = useRef(() => {
    throw new Error('Cannot call an event handler while rendering.');
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = fn;
  }, [fn, ...dependencies]);

  return useCallback(() => {
    const fn = ref.current;
    return fn();
  }, [ref]);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgEQKZlQOwCZYMYCeAMsAM4wA0cArqagMICGANswEaN4DWVtqAogDNBqPJRp0ASqkFwAvnEFQIIOAHIoqTjDUBuALAAoI6gAekWIuqYxwCJgkCAblhhNWHbgB4AKnDMwWNikcAAUAHSRjFAA5qQAXHCMmAQA2gC6AJRwALwAfHCYqC5QeaGCmIk%20VLgYOPjAqAko6EH4xGQw2QhGcHB49uRwmrI5jtKCoaHZ%20Yi9fXAwABbKAO6FqOv8UMpQoWpMmJgQ8HgszEkOxa5wS8nYzKhQcKtLwI-DbVDAmDHhapkDIY%20nJAUZ5nwhCIxFMZgUesCFiNwnhqDsbmMKkCQVRUhUqJFwrU2jZGqQskD5poYGiHHx3OxOFxYbl4fM%20gNMEMKrlPoIUWjNJgYNikagaVAHBVpqK5LiRhSjHIgA)

Comment: The return types of `fn` should be `any`, `never` should be one of them. If I pass a function with string return type like `useEventCallback(() => '', []);`, TSC will throw new error.

Comment: If you are throwing an error, return type is `never`. In your example you are throwing an error